# What does a Chinese citizen need to provide for a tourist visa to Italy?

Tags: visas, italy, chinese-citizens

I am planning to visit Italy this fall, I hold a Chinese passport and my wife is a US citizen. I am not working but not formally retired; we depend on family income and savings. What do I need to prepare for the visa?

Comment: is it just you, or you and your wife, that will be traveling?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you have to show that you are a genuine tourist. You must be able to afford the trip, and you must show that you're likely to leave again.

- Without formal employment, you will have to show your income and cash flow in some detail. Both that you have enough money to spend a couple of thousand € on the trip, and that you have a reasonably settled lifestyle to return to.
- Your current place of residence will matter as well. There are few illegal immigrants from the US to Europe, slightly more from China, and rather more from other parts of the world.